# Proof for a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I wish to verify if my proof is valid for the following problem, please. Thanks!

Let $x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real sequence and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define
$t_n = \sup\{x_k\colon k\ge n\}$ and $s_n = \inf\{x_k\colon k\ge n\}$. Prove $t_n$ is a decreasing sequence, so for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $t_{n+1}\le t_n$.

Proof: Since $t_n = \sup\{x_n, x_{n+1}, \dots\}$ and $t_{n+1} = \sup\{x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \dots\}$. It is clear that the $\sup\{x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \dots\} \leq \sup\{x_n, x_{n+1}, \dots\}$. Therefore, $t_{n+1} \leq t_n$ and the real sequence is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Your proof  is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @rudinsimons12 Your proof is missing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a detail that can be added :

$t_n=\sup \{x_k| k\ge n\}$.

$t_{n+1}=\sup \{x_k|k\ge n+1\}$.

1) Assume $x_n \ge x_k$ for $k \ge n+1$, i.e.

$x_n$ is an upper bound for $\{x_k|k \ge n+1\}$.

Then $t_{n+1} =\sup \{x_k|k\ge n+1\} \le x_n$,

since $t_{n+1}$ is the least upper bound for $\{x_k| k \ge n+1\}$.

Obviously:

$x_n \ge x_k$, $k \ge n$, and we have

$x_n= t_n$;

Altogether

$t_{n+1} \le t_n$.

2) Assume $x_n \lt x_k$, for $k \ge n+1$.

Then

$t_n=t_{n+1}$, and we are done

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my proof, is that fine?

Comment: rudinsimons12.Of course.:)